# is it good practice to use relative path in xpath more than once

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver, xpath

I am using Selenium Webdriver-Java to automate a web application.

Suppose the html is somewhat like below:

```
<div id='a1'>
   <div>
       <div>
          <span id='s1'>sometext</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To locate a element i am using xpath as below:

```
//div[@id='a1']//span[@id='s1']
```

is this xpath a good practice

or is it bad practice to use relative path(//) twice in a single xpath?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Here, we provide opinions on real code; generic best-practice questions are off-topic. Please include real code and some context for what you are trying to do.  (For example, are you testing that the `s1` element exists and that it has an `a1` ancestor? Or are you really only interested in the `s1`?)

Answer (score 1):

> is it bad practice to use relative path(//) twice in a single xpath?

It would depend on the HTML source of the code - how many elements are there in the path between the nodes, how unique are the elements and their attributes, in general.

In this case though, it is perfectly okay - it is even better than having:

```
//div[@id='a1']/div/div/span[@id='s1']
```

because here we check more nodes on the way to `span` and we start to depend on the markup even more than before - this means our locator is more fragile, less resistant to a design/layout change.

In general, *you should avoid using XPath locators if possible - they are the slowest and the least readable*. Selenium offers much more options for locating elements:

- by CSS selector:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#a1 #s1"));
  ```
- by ID:

  ```
  WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.id("a1"));
  WebElement child = parent.findElement(By.id("s1"));
  ```

Note that we are not checking tag names here at all - it is a good idea to not use "container"-type tags like `div` and `span` inside locators.

IDs are the fastest available locators - locating an element by id internally comes down to executing `getElementById()` which is optimized by the modern browsers. IDs are also unique by definition (even though nothing prevents you to create two or more elements with the same ID).